# Creation of Multiple Actions on Onclick APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working in Oracle APEX .i want to create multiple actions onclick on one  button.I want to insert the Table values and also want to redirect page in the same data base.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button is submitting the page then you can create any number of processes, calculations, validations and branches that can be run conditionally for that specific button.

Your table insert would be a Process and your redirect will be a Branch.